# Invalid response from Apache http /.well-known/acme-challenge

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf, lets-encrypt

I've Apache httpd server version 2.4.33 working under ubuntu bionic. I've compiled with the following configure

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2 --enable-pie --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-so --disable-include --enable-lua --enable-deflate --enable-headers --enable-expires --enable-http2 --with-nghttp2=/opt/nghttp2 --enable-ssl=shared --with-ssl=/opt/openssl --with-openssl=/opt/openssl --with-crypto --enable-module=ssl --enable-mpms-shared=all --with-mpm=event --enable-rewrite --with-z=${HOME}/apache24/httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}/srclib/zlib --enable-md --enable-fcgid --with-included-apr CFLAGS="-O0 -g3 -fsanitize=address"
```

I want to install let's encrypt ACME and the error provided is:

```
example.com:Verify error:Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/gteJptcJbMgc7jmGx1EO6-Uf0Ox2bELI44nT6oYcJOI:
```

I've tried almost everything. changed ownership with chown -R user:user htdocs/, changed permissions to chmod 755 -R htdocs even to 777 but it can't open acme-challenge. I've modified httpd.conf many times and there's not any different response

Comment: Apache error logs might shed some light. Do you have the `acme-challenge` folder created? Is there a `.htaccess` anywhere that might be interfering? If you put a simple text file in your `htdocs`, can you view it with a browser? Lots of basic Apache conf debugging that might apply here, but you haven't demonstrated that you've done any of it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've acme-challenge created when accessing it gives me 404 but .well-known is okay. I can create files and folders normally without any problem and it can be viewed via browser. I don't have any kind of .htaccess files

Comment: So, you can see files under `.well-known`, but not under `.well-known/acme-challenge`? It's either permissions, or a .htaccess file, or a pretty specific Apache config issue, or a typo in a file name.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution as I've compiled my own webserver from apache

1. configure with the following  `./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-so --enable-md --enable-deflate --enable-headers --enable-http2 --with-nghttp2=/opt/nghttp2 --enable-ssl=shared --with-ssl=/opt/openssl --with-openssl=/opt/openssl --with-crypto --enable-module=ssl --enable-mpms-shared=all --with-mpm=event --enable-rewrite --with-z=/home/vrt/apache24/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/zlib --enable-fcgid --with-included-apr CFLAGS="-O0 -g3"`
2. compile and install with `$make && sudo make install`
3. when it's finally installed just modify the httpd.conf to listen to port number 5002
4. run your certbot or acme.sh and Viola! I shouldn't have enabled md before the initial certificate production

I hope it helps someone in the future

Comment: There is no solution that does not involve compiling Apache from scratch?